# UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ipad, uitapgesturerecognizer

How can I get location in view using the

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
}
```

method?

Answer (score 0):

gesture recognizer has locationInView:view method.
also UIGestureRecognizer has .view property, so you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```
-(void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.navigationController.toolbar];
CGRect nextButtonRect = CGRectMake(self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.width * 2 / 3,
                                   0,
                                   self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.width / 3,
                                   self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height);

CGRect previousButtonRect = CGRectMake(0,
                                   0,
                                   self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.width / 3,
                                   self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height);

if (CGRectContainsPoint(previousButtonRect, p))
    [self tapOnPreviousNews];

if (CGRectContainsPoint(nextButtonRect, p))
    [self tapOnNextNews];
}
```